# Wordpress: url redirect to https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Facing problem in urls redirect. Urls are as following:

```
www.mysite.com redirects to [http s://www.mysite.com] = OK.
mysite.com displays Privacy Error = Failed.
[http ://mysite.com] displays Privacy Error = Failed.
[http s://mysite.com] displays Privacy Error = Failed.
[http ://www.mysite.com] redirects to [http s://www.mysite.com] = OK.
```

Note:

I've tried Wordpress HTTPS plugin.

Edit .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Edit wp-config.php file too.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

But no luck. Can anyone figure it out that where the things are going wrong.

Comment: I've had the problem too once, and left with no solution I just added some Javascript, checking if `document.location.protocol === 'http:'` and then setting it to' https:'

Comment: Yes VirginieLBG is right. Nice solution…

Comment: @VirginieLGB: Nice one, it was really helpful but my problem was solved through .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the host in `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` to the domain name that your SSL certificate verifies.

It sounds like your SSL certificate will only verify `www.example.com` not `example.com`, therefore if you make the request `http://example.com` you will be redirected to `https://example.com` which is not verified by your certificate... and thus you get an error.

Instead, change your rule to:

`RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

This also has the added benefit of improving SEO.

PS: Also, for debugging purposes, use `R=307` to prevent the redirect from being cached by your browser

Comment: Thanks man, nearly solved the all issues except the  4th one.

Comment: i.e.

    [http s://mysite.com] displays Privacy Error = Failed.

Comment: It will be impossible to secure https://example.com without getting a new certificate that validates example.com

Comment: Ok. I'll try for this. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```